# Passing data from server-side to client-side using node js and jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, get, client-side, server-side

Good evening,

I'm newbie on node, so I'm facing problems while trying to write any data on client side from the server. First of all, on client side, I'm trying this:

```
$.get("myNode.js", function( data ) {
  var bottle = JSON.parse(data);
  var name = bottle.name;
  alert(name)
});
```

And on server side to be honest I have no idea what to put on, I've tried:
       `app.get("myNode.js", function(require, response){
           response.json({ name: "example" });
       });`

While having these:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

However I don't think it works that way, and can't figure out how the server side can make a response to client side. So any help would be nice.

The other thing that bothers me, how can I tell a server which GET it should give me, If I have different elements on the page and those should give me different information from server, how can I specify those GET's?

Any help appreaciated, thank you for your time and support!

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Okay So I got now on my Client side:

```
$("#Beer").click(function(){
$.get("/getMyData", function( data ) {
  var bottle = JSON.parse(data);
  var name = bottle.name;
  alert(name)
});
})
```

And on server side:

```
      http.createServer(function(req, res) {/*Reads File and writes it*/
      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
        var filename = "." + q.pathname;
        fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.write(data);
      res.end();
        })
  /*App get*/      
     app.get("/getMyData", function(require, response){
         response.json({ name: "example" });
     });
  }).listen(8080);
```

I still think I'm doing something not quite well, which I don't understand. So far it alerts me nothing. Does app get is used as it should be? and Does response.json really sends data?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have posted you seem a little confused about how urls are working within your app. When you set up your `app.get()`, the first argument you pass in is the endpoint. It could look like:

```
app.get("/getMyData", function(req, res) {...});
```

If you are running this on a local server you could then access this endpoint by going to `http://localhost:8080/getMyData` in a browser. Then using JQuery's get method you can pass in that exact url and it should return some data for you.

If you want multiple endpoints you can just add more `app.get()` functions with different endpoint names like `/getMyData2`.